# TimescaleDB/PostgreSQL: how to use unique constraint when creating hypertables?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, timescaledb

I am trying to create a table in PostgreSQL to contain lots of data and for that reason I want to use timescales hypertable as in the example below.

```
CREATE TABLE "datapoints" (
  "tstz" timestamptz NOT NULL,
  "id" bigserial UNIQUE NOT NULL,  
  "entity_id" bigint NOT NULL,
  "value" real NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("id", "tstz", "entity_id")
);

SELECT create_hypertable('datapoints','tstz');
```

However, this throws an error - shown below. As far as I have figured out the error arise since the unique constraint isn't allowed in hypertables, but I really need the uniqueness. So does anyone have an idea on how to solve it or work around it?

```
ERROR:  cannot create a unique index without the column "tstz" (used in partitioning)
SQL state: TS103
```

Comment: Can you explain the semantics of column `id`? Is it a generated identifier for each row? Is it counter based and does it monotonically increase?

Comment: Yes to all your questions (if I understood them correctly).

Comment: Then in a sense you have two time dimension columns: `tstz` and `id`. I guess the first one is used in queries, right? What is the goal of `id`? Is it for foreign key constraint, which you mentioned below?
It is not very common to have a unique id in timeseries data, since it is expensive to maintain. How is `id` column used?

Comment: You are perfectly right. It is used as a foreign key constraint to give metadata about the datapoint.

Comment: Then I suggest to merge the hypertable and the table, which references the time series data. What is the reason now for storing data into two tables?

Comment: To minimize redundancy - our full database consist of ~ 20 tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to avoid that.

TimescaleDB uses PostgreSQL partitioning, and it is not possible to have a primary key or unique constraint on a partitioned table **that does not contain the partitioning key**.

The reason behind that is that an index on a partitioned table consists of individual indexes on the partitions (these are the partitions of the *partitioned index*). Now the only way to guarantee uniqueness for such a partitioned index is to have the uniqueness implicit in the definition, which is only the case if the partitioning key is part of the index.

So you either have to sacrifice the uniqueness constraint on `id` (which is pretty much given if you use a sequence) or you have to do without partitioning.

Comment: Thanks. Our issue is that "someone" potentially could add an entry manually which would give the possibility of non-uniqueness, but I think the risk of that is low. Maybe we can work with permissions on that column on its own... but thanks again for your quick answer.

Comment: Actually, this throws another problem. We want to define a foreign key, which asks for a unique constraint. Like: "ALTER TABLE "datapoints" ADD FOREIGN KEY ("entity_id") REFERENCES "entities" ("id");" gives the following error: "ERROR:  there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "entities"
SQL state: 42830"

Comment: You can solve that by adding the other columns from the referenced unique or primary key constraint to the referencing table. Again, that is the only way.

Comment: We have ~20 tables in our database and would like to have it like that to minimize redundancy. If we should have all together, we would end up getting really wide tables - is there really no way around that?

Comment: Of course you want to normalize. The solution to having a foreign key is: 1) remove the `UNIQUE` constraint 2) remove `entity_id` from the primary key so that it is on `(id, tstz)` 3) have both columns (`id` and `tstz`) in the referencing tables. Then you can define your foreign key.

Comment: Thanks again for all your answers - with your suggestion we end up with a one-to-one relation and we would like to have a one-to-many relation. I think I will make a new post with a better example to illustrate the problem, but i have learned a lot so far.

Comment: To be frank, supporting unique constraints on non-partitioning columns would be well in spirit of timescaledb, as long as they take care about auto partitioning, why not take care of maintaining indexes on individual partitions as well?